# How to add directive dependency in App file using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which I want to add in my app file so that it can be used in controller.
This is the folder structure:
[image]

This is my directive dragAndDrop.js file :

```
var app= angular.module('rulesApp',[]);
  app.directive('droppable', function() {
    return {
    //some code here
}
}
```

this is my rulesApp file:

```
var app = angular.module('rulesApp', []);
```

But with this code it is not picking directive file. This is the structure created on chrome. But it does not contain dragAndDrop.js file.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: check the file as its showing ? mark on it. Is that included in your solutions?

Comment: have you included the 'dragAndDrop.js' file in your html/php/jsp file which includes your scripts?

Comment: I think the ? may be because it is a newly created file..not committed in SVN yet

Comment: Hopefully you are not yet added dragAndDrop.js file either in correct path in your file or not yet committed in your SVN file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but to me it seems like you are defining the module twice.

Try this instead:

```
var app= angular.module('rulesApp')
      .directive('droppable', function() {
          return {
              //some code here
          }
      }
```

This is how you define the module:

```
var app = angular.module('rulesApp', []);
```

This is how you get a module

```
var app = angular.module('rulesApp');
```